# DataTables - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a very simple (in my mind) JSON data from an API request that i'd like to visualise using DataTables (see below). But i'm facing the following error:

- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Appreciate your help. Thank you!

```
{
    "task_id": "dac94ac5-2987-4218-b568-5a27c246980f",
    "task_name": "taskmanager.tasks.task_run_device_discovery",
    "task_result": {
      "completed": true,
      "progress": [
        "Placing device: DUT-C1117-4PLTEEA console into *LOCKED* state...",
        "Initiating connection to: DUT-C1117-4PLTEEA @ 10.113.128.141",
        "Getting show version output...",
        "Checking whether RESTCONF is enabled...",
        "Updating database with show version output...",
        "Restconf is not enabled on the device",
        "Interface: Vlan1 already in the database...",
        "Updating: Vlan1 ***SUBNET/STATUS/MTU*** information...",
        "Interface: Ethernet0/3/0 already in the database...",
        "Updating: Ethernet0/3/0 ***SUBNET/STATUS/MTU*** information...",
        "Interface: ATM0/3/0 already in the database...",
        "Updating: ATM0/3/0 ***SUBNET/STATUS/MTU*** information...",
        "Interface: Cellular0/2/1 already in the database...",
        "Updating: Cellular0/2/1 ***SUBNET/STATUS/MTU*** information...",
        "Interface: Cellular0/2/0 already in the database...",
        "Updating: Cellular0/2/0 ***SUBNET/STATUS/MTU*** information...",
        "Interface: GigabitEthernet0/1/3 already in the database...",
        "Updating: GigabitEthernet0/1/3 ***SUBNET/STATUS/MTU*** information...",
        "Interface: GigabitEthernet0/1/2 already in the database...",
        "Updating: GigabitEthernet0/1/2 ***SUBNET/STATUS/MTU*** information...",
        "Interface: GigabitEthernet0/1/1 already in the database...",
        "Updating: GigabitEthernet0/1/1 ***SUBNET/STATUS/MTU*** information...",
        "Interface: GigabitEthernet0/1/0 already in the database...",
        "Updating: GigabitEthernet0/1/0 ***SUBNET/STATUS/MTU*** information...",
        "Interface: GigabitEthernet0/0/0 already in the database...",
        "Updating: GigabitEthernet0/0/0 ***SUBNET/STATUS/MTU*** information...",
        "Performing deleted interface check...",
        "Could not find any deleted interfaces...",
        "Closing connection to: DUT-C1117-4PLTEEA...",
        "Removing device: DUT-C1117-4PLTEEA console from *LOCKED* state..."
      ]
    },
    "task_status": "SUCCESS",
    "task_requested_by": "user:admin",
    "task_start_time": "2022-10-11T10:20:35.059Z"
  }
```

and table:

```
<table data-ajax="https://IP/api/housekeeping/housekeeping/task_results" id="example" class="display">
<thead>
   <tr>
     <th>task_id</th>
     <th>task_name</th>
     <th>task_result</th>
     <th>task_status</th>
     <th>task_requested_by</th>
     <th>task_start_time</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function () {
      var table = $('#example').DataTable({});
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Below solved my problem, "dataSrc" by default expects an array named "data"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $('#example').DataTable({
              processing: true,
              serverSide: true,
              ajax:{
                url:"https://IP/api/housekeeping/housekeeping/task_results",
                dataSrc:""
              },
              columns: [
                    { data: "task_id" },
                    { data: "task_name" },
                    { data: "task_result.completed" },
                    { data: "task_result.progress" },
                    { data: "task_status" },
                    { data: "task_requested_by" },
                    { data: "task_start_time" }
                ]
        });

    </script>
```